# Hiding the overflow of a static element (Clip-path problem w/ Edge)

Tags: css, svg, layout, clip-path

I'm making a layout that has two absolutely position elements that are positioned exactly the same. One must be cutoff by a container, while the other element will be visible outside of said container. `overflow: hidden` won't work since the container must be `position:static`in order that both of the absolute elements will be position relative to the same parent. Therefore, I've used `clip-path: inset(0 0 0 0)` which works fine for all browsers I'm concerned about, except for Edge (pre-chromium). I'm hiding the effect for IE.

Any suggestions for a solution that would work for Edge as well would be appreciated.

```css
body{
  padding: 100px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
}
.container{
  position: static;
  max-width: 1280px;
  padding: 100px;
  background: lightblue;
/*   height: 500px; */
  clip-path: inset(0 0 0 0);
}
.swoop{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}
.col{
  width: 40%;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <img class="swoop swoop-90-y" src="https://webcdn-compassion-ca.s3.amazonaws.com/_2/img/covid/swoop-90deg-yellow.svg" alt="Yellow swooping stripe" srcset="">
  <div class="container">
    <img class="swoop swoop-90-y pos-abs " src="https://webcdn-compassion-ca.s3.amazonaws.com/_2/img/covid/swoop-90deg-white.svg" alt="Yellow swooping stripe" srcset="">
      <div class="col">
        <h1>Hello world</h1>
        <p>Fusce pellentesque, leo vel posuere volutpat, erat ligula cursus metus, sed blandit dui ligula eu erat. Mauris aliquam nec sem in tincidunt. Quisque ultrices quam eget eros elementum, nec venenatis mauris varius. Sed blandit rhoncus augue id vehicula. Nulla sapien nulla, maximus in ornare et, condimentum a turpis. In vel tristique ligula. Morbi id massa quis nisi imperdiet semper. Nam convallis ut risus id tristique. Praesent tempus aliquam magna a consequat.</p>
        </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: uodate your Edge version, the code should work fine

Comment: Yes, it works fine on the chromium version, but I need to support the previous version of Edge. I'll update my question to reflect this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it differently relying on background where the trick is to use `background-attachment:fixed`

```css
body {
  padding: 100px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  background: 
   url(https://webcdn-compassion-ca.s3.amazonaws.com/_2/img/covid/swoop-90deg-yellow.svg) 
   top right fixed no-repeat;
}

.container {
  max-width: 1280px;
  padding: 100px;
  background: 
   url(https://webcdn-compassion-ca.s3.amazonaws.com/_2/img/covid/swoop-90deg-white.svg) 
   top right fixed no-repeat, 
   lightblue;
}

.col {
  width: 40%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="col">
      <h1>Hello world</h1>
      <p>Fusce pellentesque, leo vel posuere volutpat, erat ligula cursus metus, sed blandit dui ligula eu erat. Mauris aliquam nec sem in tincidunt. Quisque ultrices quam eget eros elementum, nec venenatis mauris varius. Sed blandit rhoncus augue id vehicula.
        Nulla sapien nulla, maximus in ornare et, condimentum a turpis. In vel tristique ligula. Morbi id massa quis nisi imperdiet semper. Nam convallis ut risus id tristique. Praesent tempus aliquam magna a consequat.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Also like below where you have to adjust the `background-position` of the child to match the one of the parent

```css
body {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  max-width: 1280px;
  padding:80px;
  background: 
   url(https://webcdn-compassion-ca.s3.amazonaws.com/_2/img/covid/swoop-90deg-yellow.svg) 
   calc(50% + 200px) 0 no-repeat;
}

.col {
  padding: 100px;
  width:50%;
  margin:auto;
  background: 
   url(https://webcdn-compassion-ca.s3.amazonaws.com/_2/img/covid/swoop-90deg-white.svg) 
   calc(50% + 200px) -80px no-repeat, 
   lightblue;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="col">
      <h1>Hello world</h1>
      <p>Fusce pellentesque, leo vel posuere volutpat, erat ligula cursus metus, sed blandit dui ligula eu erat. Mauris aliquam nec sem in tincidunt. Quisque ultrices quam eget eros elementum, nec venenatis mauris varius. Sed blandit rhoncus augue id vehicula.
        Nulla sapien nulla, maximus in ornare et, condimentum a turpis. In vel tristique ligula. Morbi id massa quis nisi imperdiet semper. Nam convallis ut risus id tristique. Praesent tempus aliquam magna a consequat.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="container">
    <div class="col">
      <h1>Hello world</h1>
      <p>Fusce pellentesque, leo vel posuere volutpat, erat ligula cursus metus, sed blandit dui ligula eu erat. Mauris aliquam nec sem in tincidunt. Quisque ultrices quam eget eros elementum, nec venenatis mauris varius. Sed blandit rhoncus augue id vehicula.
        Nulla sapien nulla, maximus in ornare et, condimentum a turpis. In vel tristique ligula. Morbi id massa quis nisi imperdiet semper. Nam convallis ut risus id tristique. Praesent tempus aliquam magna a consequat.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response @Termani. It's a good work around (a method I didn't consider), but, unfortunately, the use case doesn't work for me since I'm using multiple instances of this "clipping" over an entire page and the `fixed` position when scrolling doesn't work for the design. I want it to be statically positioned (ie. positioned relative to parent rather than positioned relative to browser viewport).

Comment: @E-video you can still do it without fixed but you are required to do some calculation to correctly set the position (check the update)

Comment: Yes!! The `calc()` positioning works for my use case. Thanks a lot @Temani. I appreciate the effort!